# How do i launch media files like mp4 using my app

Tags: c#, uwp

How do i Launch Media files like Mp4 or mp3 using my UWP application, so that when i right click on an associated file like mp4 file i can be able to open it with my app, or even when i double click on it....any ideas

Comment: no this solution here http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=1197 doesnt really answer me.....how do i get the mp4 file to play using the media element like i that case it was getting the text to display on the textbox....thats what i want

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your question is actually like how to Open your App with a File Association, and this file format is .mp3 or .mp4.

To do this, you can refer to the [this blog](http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=1197), basically you need to declare in your apps manifest and then handle the event first in your app's `OnFileActivated` method.

> so that when i right click on an associated file like mp4 file i can be able to open it with my app

Since you are trying to open file with "right click", not "double click", your app should be shown in the "Open with..." options, even your app is not shown, you can find it by selecting "More Apps", and then find your app and open the file with your app. There will be no problem unless you double click the file, by double clicking, it will open the file using the default app. And you can set the default app in the `Settings` -> `Default apps` like the image below:
[image]

Comment: no this solution here http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=1197 doesnt really answer me.....how do i get the mp4 file to play using the media element like i that case it was getting the text to display on the textbox....thats what i want